# Facebook Page Post Api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I'm administrator of a page on facebook account. How do I post this page to api ?

And I, how the code will get a access_token  ?

Comment: yes i do, i add post in page using api

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Follow this steps to make:

1. Take `manage_pages` [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)
2. Get Page Access_token from `https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>`
3. Post your message on page using: `https://graph.facebook.com/<Page_ID>/feed?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN_TAKEN_FROM_STEP2>&message=uuuuhhhuuu...`
4. Open your page and check that... :)

Comment: What does it mean 'take `manage_pages` permissions'? How can I take it? I have only page account (with no appid/secret key). Thanks